# Below Code is not printing anything

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int ma(float array[], int N)
{
    int k = 0;
    float max = array[k];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        if (array[i] > max) {
            max = array[i];
            k = i;
        }
    }
    return k;
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    while (t--) {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        int w[n], p[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            cin >> w[i];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            cin >> p[i];
        float x[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            x[i] = p[i] / w[i];
        int weigth = 0, profit = 0;
        while (weigth <= 20) {
            // int k=distance(x, max_element(x, x + n));
            // int k=  std::distance(x, max_element(x, x + sizeof(x)/sizeof(x)));
            int k = ma(x, n);
            weigth = weigth + w[k];
            profit = profit + p[k];
            x[k] = p[k] = w[k] = 0;
        }
        cout << weigth << endl
             << profit << endl;
    }
}
```

The above code is not printing anything. If you want the question refer to ["catch-the-match"](https://www.hackerearth.com/challenge/college/code-arena1/algorithm/catch-the-match/):

Comment: `int t; while(t--)` — You forgot to initialize `t`

Comment: "If you want the question... " .. what? If you want an answer you should provide a question in the question and not hidden behind a link that asks me to login somewhere

Comment: you probably want `int t=N` where N is any nonzero value(e.g. 10), you should decide what the value is As I can't see the question without logging in

Comment: Can I suggest starting off with something simpler - and [learning how to use your debugger](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Answer (score 2):

your code is not even compiling,

you can not do this in C++

```
int n;
cin >> n;
int w[n], p[n];
```

because n must be a constant at compiling time, on the other hand doing this:

```
int t;
while (t--) {
```

is producing an unpredictable number of iterations in the loop since t is not initialized

Comment: Thanks..I just slipped my finger & forgot to add cin>>t

Comment: @PRATIKAHUJA That's a big slip to skip 6 or so characters.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare `int n` as a `const int n` in order for you code to compile correctly.